# When I create Intent, he created with value null

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have the next code in my application, I try start Activity, but application force closed in emulator.

```
  public class LoginActivity extends Activity { 

static Button btnLogin; 
public static final String TAG="---------2-----";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.logining);  

    btnLogin =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogon);          
}

public void onClickLogon(View view){        
    AscTaskLogin LoginTask = new AscTaskLogin(this);
    LoginTask.execute("1","1");     
}

public static void LOGV(final String tag, String message){
    if(BuildConfig.DEBUG){
        Log.v(tag, message);
    }
}
```

}

function ResultAsync work after AsyncTask. this my AsynckTask

```
     public class AscTaskLogin extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
LoginActivity mActivity;

 public AscTaskLogin(Activity activity) {
    this.mActivity = mActivity;
 }

    public static final String TAG="---------2-----";

     protected void onPreExecute() {            
         LoginActivity.LOGV(TAG, "PreExecite -------" );
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {          
        LoginActivity.LOGV(TAG, "PostExecite -------" );            
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClass(mActivity, Copy.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        mActivity .startActivity(i);
    }   


    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... sendData) {
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LoginActivity.LOGV(TAG, "doInBackground ------");           
        return true; 
    }
```

}

in Manifest file i writed about activity.

```
     <activity android:name="LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter></activity>
    <activity android:name="MainActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="Copy"></activity>
```

application close with next errors

```
02-04 14:55:49.639: V/---------2-----(3065): doInBackground ------
02-04 14:55:49.639: V/---------2-----(3065): PostExecite -------
02-04 14:55:49.639: D/AndroidRuntime(3065): Shutting down VM
02-04 14:55:49.639: W/dalvikvm(3065): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa000f180)
02-04 14:55:49.639: E/AndroidRuntime(3065): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-04 14:55:49.639: E/AndroidRuntime(3065): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-04 14:55:49.639: E/AndroidRuntime(3065):     at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
02-04 14:55:49.639: E/AndroidRuntime(3065):     at android.content.Intent.setClass(Intent.java:5502)
02-04 14:55:49.639: E/AndroidRuntime(3065):     at com.example.notmyself.AscTaskLogin.onPostExecute(AscTaskLogin.java:28)
02-04 14:55:49.639: E/AndroidRuntime(3065):     at com.example.notmyself.AscTaskLogin.onPostExecute(AscTaskLogin.java:1)
02-04 14:55:49.639: E/AndroidRuntime(3065):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
02-04 14:55:49.639: E/AndroidRuntime(3065):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
02-04 14:55:49.639: E/AndroidRuntime(3065):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
02-04 14:55:49.639: E/AndroidRuntime(3065):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-04 14:55:49.639: E/AndroidRuntime(3065):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-04 14:55:49.639: E/AndroidRuntime(3065):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-04 14:55:49.639: E/AndroidRuntime(3065):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-04 14:55:49.639: E/AndroidRuntime(3065):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-04 14:55:49.639: E/AndroidRuntime(3065):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-04 14:55:49.639: E/AndroidRuntime(3065):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-04 14:55:49.639: E/AndroidRuntime(3065):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I think - in Intent created with value - null.I haven't idea how fix this problem.

Comment: Someone more familiar with Android may be able to provide more detailed help, but the short answer is that your activity's return method is being invoked before the activity is created. You need to save the context and pass it to a constructor for a special-purpose object for the callback (this is called a *closure*) or make sure to reinitialize it in your callback method.

Comment: It my first application, I not so long ago start learn android. how make it? please, give me link on example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call intent directly from `onPostExecute` like below...

```
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    Intent i= new Intent();
    i.setClass(LoginActivity.this, Copy.class);  
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
    getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);
}
```

You need to create the task with a reference to the activity or context that spawned it.

```
public class AscTaskLogin extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

 LoginActivity mActivity;

 public AscTaskLogin(Activity activity) {
    this.mActivity = activity;
 }

 @Override
 protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
     boolean result;

     //do some stuff

     return result;
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {        
        Intent i= new Intent();
        i.setClass(mActivity, Copy.class);  
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
        mActivity.startActivity(i);       
 }
}
```

Comment: I try made 
    `protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {   
      LoginActivity.LOGV(TAG, "PostExecite -------" );      
      Intent i = new Intent();
      i.setClass(LA, Copy.class);
      i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      LA.startActivity(i);      
     }`
but still force close

Comment: I create in method onCreate() `LoginTask = new AscTaskLogin(this);` and use you're code. but still nothing. application still closing.

Comment: Yes, we got it. Thanks, very very much.
I changed my code like this
     `public AscTaskLogin(Activity activity, LoginActivity mActivity) {
     this.mActivity = mActivity;
  }`
and call like this 
     `AscTaskLogin LoginTask = new AscTaskLogin(this, this);`
it's worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are never initializing `MyContext` until you use it, that's what leads to your `NullPointerException`. :

```
i.setClass(MyContext, Copy.class);
```

The problem is the way you are initializing your Activity. You should not initialize an `Activity` instance and let it launch itself. I'd recommend starting the `Activity` from your previous `Activity`.

Also, as a side note, variables should start with a lower case letter.

Comment: AscTaskLogin must transmit data to the server and receive "true" or "false".in RsultAsync - start new activity, where i shouid starting activity? how make it? sorry, but i really don't understand.

Comment: Oh, so you want the same activity instance to start the AsyncTask and react on the result?

Comment: yes. in one Activity this two action. but I want run different Activity, on depending - true or false.

Answer (score 0):

update you `oncreate` as this:

```
    MyContext = this;
```